# shutdown.exe parameters with dashes or slashes?

Tags: windows, batch-file, shutdown

I use a call of `shutdown.exe` to reboot machines having different versions of Windows installed.

For Windows XP the command is:

```
shutdown.exe -r -f -t 01
```

For other versions of Windows I use:

```
shutdown.exe /L /R /C /Y /T:1
```

Now it seems, that the second command won't work on Windows XP. Does anybody know which versions of Windows support slashes and which dashes?

EDIT:

This is not an issue of wrong parameters. Here is a printout from an affected machine (German installation of Windows XP):

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\shutdown.exe /L /R /C /Y /T:1
Syntax: shutdown.exe [-l | -s | -r | -a] [-f] [-m \\Computer] [-t xx]
             [-c "Kommentar"] [-d up:xx:yy]

....
```

Comment: Not programming-related ? Belongs on superuser ?

Comment: I call the command from another program, so I thought I might as well post it here.

Comment: You should probably use the documented API, `InitiateSystemShutdownEx()`

Comment: Downvotes? Just move to superuser already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slashes *do* work on XP, but as Poke said you need to use lower-case. Additionally, it appears that you can't use "/l" with "/r" (which makes sense since a shutdown and restart of the computer will log users off anyway), and you shouldn't use a colon after "/t"

Eg:

```
shutdown /r /c /y /t 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `shutdown.exe /?` to find out how parameters are used, and which parameters are available. Looking at the help text (on Win7 atm), it seems that you need to lower-case those characters so they work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

i usually use dashes... on winXP and thereon...