# Windows shutdown-script: unexpected behavior

Tags: windows, batch-file, shutdown

I wrote a little script which would prompt me for an input, save that input to a text file and shutdown the PC afterwards.
This is what the code looks like:

```
@ECHO OFF

set /p input=Insert text:
echo %DATE%: %input% >> text.txt

echo The system will shutdown...
shutdown -s -f -t 3
```

When I execute the batch, it prompts me and saves the input correctly, but after displaying  `The system will shutdown...` it doesn't shut down, instead it starts over again promting me for input.

Does anyone know what causes this behavior?

Comment: I ran your code and it is working as expected. Saved the file on desktop and did the shutdown in 3 secs. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I ask the name of your batch file?  If it is named shutdown.bat it is likely getting called again rather than executing the shutdown command.  Try renaming your batch file if you would please.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see that might be wrong is that you are using `-`'s for the `shutdown` switches, which is correct in (I think) XP, but in Win7 (not sure about Vista) `shutdown /?` says to use `/`'s.

```
shutdown /s /f /t 3
```

Comment: Unfortunatly that did not help. It looks like Windows 7 supports both dashes and slashes (as someone mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317043/shutdown-exe-parameters-with-dashes-or-slashes?rq=1)